# Zookeeper / Exhibitor recurring JMX Error

Tags: apache-zookeeper, netflix-exhibitor

I don't know why this is occurring, but occasionally I will get this series of repeating errors and the zookeeper instances will go into a bad state.

```
Tue Feb 16 07:05:04 EST 2016    ERROR   ZooKeeper Server: Using config: /opt/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Tue Feb 16 07:05:04 EST 2016    ERROR   ZooKeeper Server: JMX enabled by default
Tue Feb 16 07:05:04 EST 2016    INFO    Process started via: /opt/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh
Tue Feb 16 07:05:03 EST 2016    INFO    Kill attempted result: 0
Tue Feb 16 07:05:03 EST 2016    INFO    Attempting to start/restart ZooKeeper
Tue Feb 16 07:05:03 EST 2016    INFO    Attempting to stop instance
Tue Feb 16 07:05:03 EST 2016    INFO    Restarting down/not-serving ZooKeeper after 60037 ms pause
Tue Feb 16 07:04:33 EST 2016    INFO    ZooKeeper down/not-serving waiting 30026 of 40000 ms before restarting
Tue Feb 16 07:04:05 EST 2016    INFO    ZooKeeper Server: Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
Tue Feb 16 07:04:04 EST 2016    ERROR   ZooKeeper Server: Using config: /opt/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Tue Feb 16 07:04:04 EST 2016    ERROR   ZooKeeper Server: JMX enabled by default
```

The exhibitor stuff uses shared storage on a NAS.  The servers are centOs 6.6.  It is a three node ensemble, and the one noticible problem I have seen is that the "ensemble" connection string inside of Exhibitor GUI all of a sudden becomes different between the three nodes (one node may "forget" about some of the other nodes in the ensemble).

I don't even know where to look to dig into these causes.  Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.  Its trully odd...

---

update versions

- zk: 3.4.6
- Exhibitor: 1.5.5

Comment: what versions of each are you using?

Comment: Hi Martin: versions zk: 3.4.6 Exhibitor: 1.5.5 - its been super stable over the past week, as soon as I post.